# Is it possible to clean up rubble, garbage and leaves?

Tags: fallout-4

Building a base is a great addition. But even in rough times, people would at least pick up leaves, trash and burnt sheets of paper from the ground in their living areas. Did I miss something, or is that not possible in Fallout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible in the base game.

There are mods for the PC version which aim to remove these objects, although this is accomplished by making the source texture 100% transparent -- which means those textures disappear from every area of the game that they're used.